# JAVASCRIPT:Is there a faster way to get this string split by a multi-character delimiter?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I know this is a newbie question,but I am finding a simple solution .
For example, `Resource`=>**"cancel_&MyButton"**;
I want to get a result string **"cancel"** that is a first part of Resource splitted by a multi-character delimiter **"_&"** .
`Result`=>**"cancel"**
Can you give me a fastest and simplest way?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the current approach / solution then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"cancel_&MyButton".split('_&')[0]` will give the result.